# Capsuling a tube shape in a volume

Tags: node-editor, shaders, mathematics

I have this node setup :
[image: Node setup]

I want to improve it a bit giving the cylinder light a capsule shape like that :
[image: capsuling]

This shape can be at any side, or both, you choose.

The distance of the red circle to object's bound has to be a parameter or relative to "border distance" node.
Same condition for the size (X axis) of the blue hemishpere.

it could help to have the object's axis (same as world axis) :
[image: axis]

Comment: How about _modelling it_? :P

Comment: it would be too easy! :)

Comment: I really like Chebhou's node setup because it's more simple and the "roundness" factor is really cool but i think someonewithpc's is better because it's origin independant and can be controled more efficently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after quite a bit of experimentation, this is what I came up with:
[image: cleaned noodles]

The green group (which is duplicated, because I couldn't get it to work otherwise) creates  half spheres, which I then append to the ends of a cylinder. As of now, changing the node setup is made so that the cylinder is aligned with the *Z axis*; you can model your object that way, to start, and then rotate it around, remembering *not* to apply the rotation. Also, changing the `Z Cylinder Scale` input value in the material allows you to scale the whole construction.

You can get the blend file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34439).

Comment: no need for absolute value before squaring

Comment: this looks intersting, scale and radius factors works good but with your model, not mine. checking why (and trying to understand :)) Good shot anyway!

Comment: sure it is! i'll need 1 or 2 minutes (hours) to understand that :)

Comment: Noodly speaking, i'm trying to clean up your mess!

Comment: i'm just waiting for other possible answers. If none, yours will be accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

what i did is that i control the radius of the circle along the X axis to create the capsule

[image]

the node group setup :
[image]

the last input of the node group is the ratio of X/Y 
at the moment there is no scaling option along the X axis

[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34442)

Complete (and combed) noodles :
[image]
Also changed the input
here an edit for scaling :  change the first value to scale along the X axis

[image]

Comment: looks interesting

Comment: @Bithur waiting for your review !

Comment: that's really really cool, I like your controls but someonewithpc's controls allow moving the capsule inside what is a real bonus (in his Z axis, your X axis). Can you introduce this?

Comment: @Bithur I will try to add this tomorrow, it's bedtime now

Comment: no problem, thx for your answer :) I have some comparaison to do